# A simple explanation needed in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok just a quick and simple question.

For example you have a class file called "Player".

Is

```
"this.addEventListener..."
```

the same with...

```
var player:Player = new Player();

 player.addEventListener...?
```

If not,can you please define "this" in a simple way or example

Comment: It depends on the scope of `this`. If you add the `this.addEventListener` inside the Class 'Player', than that would be the same as `player.addEventListener`

Comment: @putvande: You should make this an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the scope of `this`. If you add the `this.addEventListener` (or just `addEventListener`) inside the Class 'Player', than that would be the same as `player.addEventListener` (outside the Class 'Player').

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
But can you please further what "this" is?
It's really confusing for me @_@

Comment: @AlexisKyleSales when `this` is used inside of a class, it always references the current instance of the object. You should make yourself comfortable with OOP.